# Мультиязычная БД для приложения

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-play

Доброго времени суток.

Есть приложение-справочник, которое при установке распаковывает бд из папки assets и далее работает с ней. Собираюсь локализовать приложение на другие языки, но при таком же подходе приложение будет тащить с собой необоснованно раздутый файл БД (или несколько файлов) с разными языками.

Какие еще существуют варианты поставки такого приложения, желательно без использования своего сервера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные не могут взяться из ниоткуда. В любом случае они должны где-то храниться и должны быть сохранены на телефоне. Тут возможны варианты.

1. Таки хранить все локализации в БД.
2. В БД хранить только один перевод и скачивать с сервера нужный перевод по запросу из приложения. Сервер можно заменить на ссылку на файлообменник типа <s>Skype</s> DropBox, GoogleDrive etc

Comment: Просто была надежда, что есть некие инструменты в Google Play для подобного случая, которые я в упор не вижу, как это иногда случается

Comment: @Pavel, насколько мне известно через  Google Play можно только за бешеные деньги запросить перевод строковых ресурсов приложения(